# Migrate to Programmers SE or Workplace SE?

Tags: discussion

What do you think of migrating this questions [How to determine the skills of a software developer in a job interview?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/6555/how-to-find-out-the-skills-of-a-software-developer-in-job-interview#question) to programmers or workplace SE?

The way it is framed, doesn't specify if this is a project manager's challenge or a generic HR challenge.

FURTHER INFORMATION
I'm going to take a broad view of the topic and vote for it to stay on PMSE. Based on the fact that HR is involved in the interview, it sounds like the OP is being asked to participate to validate/confirm the technical skills of the potential candidate. This fits in with the general sense of the Human Resource knowledge area in the PMBOK. Specifically, under developing a human resource plan:

> Human resource planning is used to determine and *identify human resources with the necessary skills* required for project success (PMBOK Guide, 4th Edition 9.1 p.218 -italics are mine)

And, 9.2 Acquire Project Team

> The project manager or project management team should effectively negotiate and influence others who are in a position to provide the required human resources for the project.  (PMBOK Guide, 4th Edition 9.2 p.255)

Answer (score 2):

I'm on the fence about this one. To help decide, I think we should look at whether or not we would be talking about migrating it if the question were asking how the PM should find out the skills of a construction foreman, or determine the skills of a civil engineering team member on a project.

If the answers are still "this is not on topic for our site", then maybe finding a new home for it would be a good step.

I do know from experience on Programmers SE that career questions may be discouraged, since they've had so many duplicates clutter the site. However, they appear to be on-topic on Workplace SE.

The other concern is that the Stack Exchange team typically discourages migrations where the question doesn't have lots of detail, and something that the target site would benefit from. In other words, the migration shouldn't only benefit just the asker, but the community as a whole.

In this case, due to the lack of detail, I lean more towards outright closing, if the question is deemed to be off-topic. Unless, of course, we can edit it and improve it. :)

If off-topic, you could ask the Workplace mods if they want it. I'm personally fine with whatever you or the community decides.

### **UPDATE:**

Shog9, one of the Stack Exchange community managers, makes a great point in the  blog post titled [Respect the Community -- Your Own, and Others'](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/):

> ## Respecting your own community
>
> As members of a community, your first loyalty should be to that community. When evaluating a question, you shouldn’t be looking to push it off on some other site; instead, ask if it could be appropriate and on-topic for you, the experts who the author decided to ask. **Be a bit jealous of your site** – don’t blithely turn askers away simply because their question could be asked somewhere else. Don’t hit them over the head with your scope, help them tailor their question to fit into it – and if that means your site’s scope overlaps a bit with another site’s, so be it.
>
> Obviously, there are questions you’ll have to turn away, either because their *only* connection to your site is via the audience (“How do I make bread as a *programmer*?”), because it’s completely off-topic (“How do I cook a fish in a dishwasher?” obviously belongs on Cooking, not Home Improvement) or because they’re simply not useful or constructive. But that should be your *last* resort. Close questions with an eye toward *improvement and re-opening*, not driving users away.

In short, there's no easy answer to the dilemma of what to do with a specific question, and everyone who chimed in made some great points both for and against migration and closure. In general, I really feel like we've been doing a great job recently in terms of "respecting our community"; specifically, it's great to see our community members jump in and help new users improve their questions, which helps them get answers to questions they didn't even know they had!

Comment: Ship it to workplace and he'll get a bunch of HR specific answers. I think he's more likely to get better answers here.

Comment: As flagger of that question, I would recommend sending it to Workplace (or Programmers, as stated in my comment there). I don't believe interview questions belongs to PM, would it be only because then we'll have to draw another line about which questions are enough related to PM to be accepted, and consider if interviewee questions are fine too… I think the way this specific question is formulated is much too general to be PM-specific. It asks for tips for interviewing, and such tips belong to Workplace; as they are programmers-specific, it may even belong to Programmers.

Comment: I like the question where it is. I've seen project managers conducting awful interviews and hiring people who don't fit into their projects. If we move the question to programmers it will disappear there forever (will be hard to find by PMs). Hiring is not just about programming, however the OP is looking for developers. I don't know much about workplace SE, so that's all I can add now.

Comment: @MattiSG and aclear, I dropped a link to the question in the Workplace SE chat room. I figure that's the next best thing to migration for this unique case where the question could fit both places. Let's see how this goes. :)

Comment: @aclear16 and MattiSG, I also dropped a link in the Programmers SE chat room.